# Powershell cmd to restart machine isn't working

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have this setup as a scheduled task in windows to run this batch file:

```
powershell.exe restart-computer
EXIT
```

Powershell is working as other commands work.

The task returns 0x1 which I believe means a failure relating to permissions?

I run the task with the option to run it when I'm logged in or not and with highest privileges.

When I type restart-computer in powershell it works.

Comment: Why are you running a powershell command from a batch file? Just call `shutdown /r /t 0` in the batch file

Comment: @arco444 Even a batch file is not needed. Just call shutdown and set the switches in parameters section in Task Scheduler.

Comment: cause "user account control"do not let limited user to change on windows with out administrator perm for this pull down uac settings and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the -force parameter?

```
powershell.exe restart-computer -force
```